# Zero validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequential, train-test-split

I try to classificate on traffic signs but 12 labels and 1380 pictures and I want a race car to react on the signs. For example, a stop sign, the car should stop.

It's a common problem but here's my output of the Epoch: "Epoch 10/10
35/35 [==============================] - 5s 136ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00"

Where's the problem? My optimizer, loss, metrics, shape, images, labels?

I tried to make various models but I dont think model is the problem, but something else.
Model 1: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1KDr.png)
Model 2: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ks4m.png)

Comment: How are you loading your data?

Comment: I'm loading my data with a for loop, making a label based on the picture title for every picture. 1380 pictures with a label. The shape of the image: (1380, 128, 128, 3), and for the label: (1380, 1). 

My images DataFrame: [[[114 112 113]
  [114 112 113]
  [112 112 112]
  ...
  [165 166 161]
  [165 166 161]
  [165 166 161]]

 [[114 112 113]
  [114 112 113]
  [112 112 112]
  ...
  [165 166 161]
  [165 166 161]
  [165 166 161]]

My (unique) label DataFrame: [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7. 22. 24. 31. 35. 55.]